# Node.js express redirect to remote URL keeps failing (CORS)

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm trying to do a redirect to a payment gateway after placing an order on my Nodejs server, but none of my browsers are letting me.

Here's my code, which is coming directly from a code example of my payment service.

```
 res.writeHead(302, { Location : payment.getPaymentUrl() });
 res.end();
```

Which always results in :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.mollie.com/payscreen/pay/CtcH7nkDQr. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've configured my app to use there headers :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

    next();
});
```

Comment: When I go to `https://www.mollie.com/payscreen/pay/CtcH7nkDQr` in my browser, and then inspect the headers from the Chrome Developer Tools network tab, I cannot see any of those headers. Here's the full headers I get: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 00:46:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2142
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Whom: dc1-web-3` it actually seems to be nginx, not even nodejs. Maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took Juicy Scripter's advice and tried to use an existing online proxy to see if it worked. I didn't receive the error anymore, all seemed well, but no actual redirect took place. Not very surprising since my original request came from Angular's $http module, so the response was resolved on the client. Anyhow, I ended up returning the payment URL to my Angular app and redirected to it from there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is related to the fact that `https://www.mollie.com` doesn't respond with CORS headers, disabling cross origin requests from browser.

You will probably need to have some kind of proxy to make requests to payment gateway from server side code and not via `XMLHttpRequest`

Make a route that accept the desired payload, then send it to payment gateway, process the response and return results.

Answer (score 0):

a) If you need to forward to another web? If so, you should use this

```
res.redirect( payment.getPaymentUrl() ); // Your Url go to
```

b) If you need to send the url, send it in JSON format, so you take the HTML

In your server

```
res.json({ url : payment.getPaymentUrl() });
```

In your HTML

```
$.getJSON('MyUrl', function(data){
  console.log(data.url);
});
```

The cors domains, okay!